# How do you limit options selected in a html select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using a select tag in a form I'm making that allows multiple selections, but I want to make the maximum amount of selections upto 10. Is this possible using javascript or jquery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Tominated!

Comment: OK, i'll put it more into contect. it's an internal company email form with an automaticvally generated select box with every employee's name. I'm updating it so it will show which names you've already selected (it's a looooooong list) and so there is some client validation that you haven't selected more than 10 names (there is obviously sever side code to prevent this). The id for the select tag is "recipient_userid". i'll post what i have so far

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
 var last_valid_selection = null;

 $("#recipient_userid").change(function(event){
 
  var selected = "";
  
  $("#recipient_userid option:selected").each(function () {
   selected += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
  });


  
  $("#currentlySelected").html(selected);
  
 }).change();
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Select limit number of selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474614/multiple-select-limit-number-of-selection)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is some full code for you to use...gotta love the Google AJAX API Playground :-)

**Edit 1:** Note: this only lets you choose 5 because I didn't feel like copy/pasting another 10 options :-)

```
<!--
  copyright (c) 2009 Google inc.

  You are free to copy and use this sample.
  License can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/faq/#license
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Sample Select Maximum with jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA1XbMiDxx_BTCY2_FkPh06RRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQEerTAUcfkyrr6OwBovxn7TDAH5Q">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var last_valid_selection = null;

      $('#testbox').change(function(event) {
        if ($(this).val().length > 5) {
          alert('You can only choose 5!');
          $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
        } else {
          last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <select multiple id='testbox'>
      <option value='1'>First Option</option>
      <option value='2'>Second Option</option>
      <option value='3'>Third Option</option>
      <option value='4'>Fourth Option</option>
      <option value='5'>Fifth Option</option>
      <option value='6'>Sixth Option</option>
      <option value='7'>Seventh Option</option>
      <option value='8'>Eighth Option</option>
      <option value='9'>Ninth Option</option>
      <option value='10'>Tenth Option</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f19xuqp6/)**

​

Comment: that's almost perfect! it doesn't select it again if last_valid_selection is an array. Thanks, though!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What doesn't select it again if `last_valid_selection` is an array?

Comment: You may want to move `last_valid_selection` out of the global scope and into the `ready` anonymous function.

Comment: @Justin Johnson - Good point. I'm still confused as to what doesn't work though. Works perfectly in Chrome (can't test IE at the moment).

Comment: Works fine in FF 3.5.6 as well. I don't know what the down vote is for

Comment: it's not working with the code i have so far. i have a comment on the op with soem more info on what i'm doing

Comment: @tominated - You downvoted me because the example I gave you doesn't work for your exact situation?

Comment: @Topher, don't answer unless you're prepared to read minds! :)

Comment: @Jonathan +1 - LMAO. Thanks, I'm about to head to bed and I needed a laugh :-)

Comment: +1 Good idea using jQuery's `.val()` to get all values (unlike `.value` in JS). [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2GrYk/172/). The problem is that it doesn't work in the rare case with repeated values.

Answer (score 16):

This would limit the user to 3 options:

```
$("select").on("click", "option", function () {
    if ( 3 <= $(this).siblings(":selected").length ) {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GrYk/

Comment: This won't work if we use keyboard, or a glide'n click.

Answer (score 5):

This answer works in those cases:

- Normal click
- Only mousedown (mouse is moved outside before mouseup)
- Keyboard
- If there are different options with the same value

Code:

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
    if (this.selectedOptions.length < 4) {
        $(this).find(':selected').addClass('selected');
        $(this).find(':not(:selected)').removeClass('selected');
    }else
        $(this)
        .find(':selected:not(.selected)')
        .prop('selected', false);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z97v2/1/)

Or, for old browsers that don't support `selectedOptions`,

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
    var $sel = $(this).find(':selected');
    if ($sel.length < 4) {
        $sel.addClass('selected');
        $(this).find(':not(:selected)').removeClass('selected');
    }else
        $(this)
        .find(':selected:not(.selected)')
        .prop('selected', false);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z97v2/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery you can attach a function to the change event and since it is a multiple select the val() will be an array. You can always check the length of the array and do something if its a predefined size. The following code demonstrates how you will know how many items are selected.

```
  $("#select").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val().length);
  });
```

Comment: that will help a lot. is there a way to deselect evrything in a select box, also?

Comment: @tominated - Using jQuery, you can simply call `$('#myselectbox_id').val(null);`

Comment: You can use this:  `$("#select").val([]);` to set no options in the select list.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out! here's the resulting code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var last_valid_selection = null;
var selected = "";

$("#recipient_userid").change(function(event){

    if ($(this).val().length > 10) {

        alert('You can only choose 10!');
        $(this).val(last_valid_selection);

    } else {

        last_valid_selection = $("#recipient_userid").val();

        $("#recipient_userid option:selected").each(function () {
            selected += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
        });

        $("#currentlySelected").html(selected);
        selected = "";
    }

}).change();
});
```

Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: Tominated, this is not a forum. Your contributes ought only exist in the original question (you can edit it as much as you like). You should accept one of the many fine answers that were provided here.

Comment: Tominated, Jonathan is absolutely correct. The idea is to ask a question and select the best answer (you even get a few reputation for doing so). Very rarely do I not select an answer and even more rare is it that I answer my own question. However, this community is here to help each other, and I'm glad we helped you.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was unaware about that.

Answer (score 1):

I basically merged a couple of the provided answers to make something specific to a particular ID:

```
$("#mySelect").on("click", "option", function(){
    var max = 3;
    if ( max <= $(this).siblings(":selected").length ) {
        alert("Only " + max + " selections allowed.");
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
    }
});
```

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
  $("select").change(function () {
      if($("select option:selected").length > 3) {
          //your code here
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Voila! 
No Jquery necessary.

```
    var is = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectCountryCode.length; i++) {
        if (selectCountryCode.options[i].selected) {
            is++;
        }
        if (is > 3) {
            selectCountryCode.options[i].selected = false;              
        }
    }
```

Jilusan

Comment: This example seems incomplete, perhaps by intent since then it would involve jQuery? What is selectCountryCode?

Comment: There's no need to avoid jQuery; it is anyway needed to run Selectize.

Answer (score 0):

Here a pure vanilla JavaScript example, based on jilu's example.

```
const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('select[multiple]');

selectEls.forEach((selectEl) => {
    selectEl.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

        const currentEl = e.currentTarget;

        let is = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < currentEl.length; i++) {
            if (currentEl.options[i].selected) {
                is++;
            }
            if (is > 3) { // if you want more than 3 selected options, change the number here
                currentEl.options[i].selected = false;
            }
        }

    })
});
```