# select multiselect option limit up to 2

Tags: javascript, html, multi-select

I am using multiselect for different subject's I want to limit the select up to 2 and make the other's disabled in the same way if user deselect, Again the option must be available for the user.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="subjects" name="subjects[]" style="float:left;width:205px;" size="5">
  <option value='1'>subject1</option>
  <option value='2'>subject2</option>
  <option value='3'>subject3</option>
  <option value='3'>subject3</option>
</select>
```

So far I have achieved to deselect only the last option which was selected after 2 and the code is as follow

```
    /**
     * Make sure the subject's limit is 2
     */
    $(".subjects option").click(function(e){

        if ($(this).parent().val().length > 2) {
            $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046205/how-do-you-limit-options-selected-in-a-html-select-box

Comment: Thank's for the reply but I want to make all the remaining options disabled and in the link you provided it's only making the last option deselect.

Comment: Here is an example using pure javascript (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135210/html-multiselect-limit)

Comment: I suspect you can't selectively disable option elements in a way that will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 6):

Improved jQuery example, notice the (else enable) option, this fixes a bug on previous examples that disabled the select options permanently. Also removed the "Please select only two options." error message when possible.
http://jsfiddle.net/c9CkG/25/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("select").on("change", function(){
  var msg = $("#msg");

  var count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++)
  {
    var option = this.options[i];

    option.selected ? count++ : null;

    if (count > 2)
    {
        option.selected = false;
        option.disabled = true;
        msg.html("Please select only two options.");
    }else{
        option.disabled = false;
        msg.html("");
    }
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 3):

As an improvment on RobG's answer, you could unselect an option if it makes count > 2.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/c9CkG/3/ for a working example using jQuery.

```
function checkSelected(el) {
  var msgEl = document.getElementById('msg');
  var count = 0;

  for (var i=0, iLen=el.options.length; i<iLen; i++)

      el.options[i].selected? count++ : null;

      // Deselect the option.
      if (count > 2) {
          el.options[i].selected = false;
          el.options[i].disabled = true;

          msgEl.innerHTML = 'Please select only two options';
      }
}
```

Comment: Almost close but When the user deselect any one of the selected option the other option should be again available for selecting

Comment: This should be simple enough for you to implement, on a change see if the max has been reached, the change is a deselect and it's not disabled, then enable the other options.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will do the job:

```
function checkSelected(el) {
  var msgEl = document.getElementById('msg');
  var count = 0;

  for (var i=0, iLen=el.options.length; i<iLen; i++)
      el.options[i].selected? count++ : null;

  msgEl.innerHTML = count > 2? 'Please select only two options' : '';
}
</script>

<span>Please select a maximum of two options:</span>
<select multiple onchange="checkSelected(this);">
  <option>0
  <option>1
  <option>2
  <option>3
</select>
<br>
<span id="msg"></span>
```

I don't think it's a good idea to disable options, you only care that only two are selected when the form is submitted. Until then, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var last_valid_selection = null;

  $('#testbox').change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 5) {
      alert('You can only choose 5!');
      $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
    } else {
      last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.