# django admin - manytomany filter_horizontal - limit to three choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

one of my weird wishes is that I want to make the `filter_horizontal` ManytoMany select box in admin page only selectable up to three items. the fourth item should not be selectable.

how is it possible? I am thinking about overriding the save method of the object but that seems to be too "late" step somehow, is there any way to do this before save process? like any attribute on admin class field or model field that i might not have heard of?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using jquery, this would save all the serverside overhead;

in your model admin add this:

```
 class Media:
        js = ('PATHA_AFTER_STATIC/limitchoice.js', )
```

Put your limitchoice.js in the **statics/** folder (credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2046293/288387)

```
$("id_MODELNAME_to").on("change", "option", function () {
    if ( 3 <= $(this).siblings(":selected").length ) {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        alert("Only 3 choices allowed");
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note the id of your manytomany field **id_MODELNAME_to** wich points to the **second box**.

Hope it helps