# Multiple Select limit number of selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want user to select maximum of only three options from multiple select options. I tried this code so far:

```
<select id="userRequest_activity" required name="activity[]" class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2">Bungee Jumping</option>
    <option value="3">Camping</option>
    <option value="5">Mountain Biking</option>
    <option value="6">Rappelling</option>
    <option value="7">Rock Climbing / Bouldering</option>
    <option value="8">Skiing</option>
    <option value="10">Wild Life (Safari)</option>
    <option value="11">Canoeing &amp; Kayaking</option>
    <option value="12">Rafting</option>
    <option value="13">Sailing</option>
    <option value="14">Scuba Diving</option>
    <option value="15">Snorkeling</option>
    <option value="16">Surfing</option>
    <option value="18">Hang Gliding</option>
    <option value="19">Hot-air Ballooning</option>
    <option value="20">Micro-light Aircrafts</option>
    <option value="21">Paragliding</option>
    <option value="22">Paramotoring</option>
    <option value="23">Parasailing</option>
    <option value="24">Skydiving / Parachuting</option>
    <option value="25">Zip-line / Flying Fox</option>
    <option value="26">Caving</option>
    <option value="27">Cycling</option>
    <option value="28">Fishing &amp; Angling</option>
    <option value="29">Motorbike trips</option>
    <option value="30">Nature Walks</option>
    <option value="31">Road Trips</option>
    <option value="32">Zorbing</option>
    <option value="33">Trekking Hiking and Mountaineering</option>
    <option value="34">Backpacking</option>
    <option value="61">Water</option>
</select>
```

The javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select").change(function() {
    if ($("select option:selected").length > 3) {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        alert('You can select upto 3 options only');
    }
});
</script>
```

This code shows the alert box when selected more than 3 options but still allow access to select the 4th, 5th, 6th and so on selections with the alert box appearing. How to validate this?

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2046293/3342969

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this...

Check length and deselect after reach maximum select

```
<select id="userRequest_activity" required name="activity[]" class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2">Bungee Jumping</option>
    <option value="3">Camping</option>
    <option value="5">Mountain Biking</option>
    <option value="6">Rappelling</option>
    <option value="7">Rock Climbing / Bouldering</option>
    <option value="8">Skiing</option>
    <option value="10">Wild Life (Safari)</option>
    <option value="11">Canoeing &amp; Kayaking</option>
    <option value="12">Rafting</option>
    <option value="13">Sailing</option>
    <option value="14">Scuba Diving</option>
    <option value="15">Snorkeling</option>
    <option value="16">Surfing</option>
    <option value="18">Hang Gliding</option>
    <option value="19">Hot-air Ballooning</option>
    <option value="20">Micro-light Aircrafts</option>
    <option value="21">Paragliding</option>
    <option value="22">Paramotoring</option>
    <option value="23">Parasailing</option>
    <option value="24">Skydiving / Parachuting</option>
    <option value="25">Zip-line / Flying Fox</option>
    <option value="26">Caving</option>
    <option value="27">Cycling</option>
    <option value="28">Fishing &amp; Angling</option>
    <option value="29">Motorbike trips</option>
    <option value="30">Nature Walks</option>
    <option value="31">Road Trips</option>
    <option value="32">Zorbing</option>
    <option value="33">Trekking Hiking and Mountaineering</option>
    <option value="34">Backpacking</option>
    <option value="61">Water</option>
</select>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {

          var last_valid_selection = null;

          $('#userRequest_activity').change(function(event) {

            if ($(this).val().length > 3) {

              $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
            } else {
              last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
            }
          });
        });
        </script>
```

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/9c3sevuv/

Comment: I  post my answer check it and let me know

Comment: For those that don't know, instead of just setting a JS variable, you could set a custom attribute on the dropdown using .attr(), then retrieve that on .change(). This is nice and helps if you have multiple dropdowns that need this limitation.

Comment: Can this be doable WITHOUT a <select> and <option> format? Such as, just regular DIV's that have a class applied to them when clicked? Such as an 'active' class for instance that would visually show them as active?

Comment: The simplest implementation! Cool!

Answer (score 7):

You are using `this` inside `change` event, which is reference to `select`.

Try this:

```
$("select").on('click', 'option', function() {
    if ($("select option:selected").length > 3) {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        // alert('You can select upto 3 options only');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tmkzebnj/

**EDIT**

```
$("select").on('change', function(e) {
    if (Object.keys($(this).val()).length > 3) {
        $('option[value="' + $(this).val().toString().split(',')[3] + '"]').prop('selected', false);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tmkzebnj/1/

Comment: @Tushar this is working fine in the jsfiddle but not on my localhost....why so any idea? This letting user select all the options

Comment: working fine now....it shows only three selections now no matter how many options user have selected

Comment: Your edit example worked perfectly. The previous one had some issues. Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the unselected options once the user selected the maximum limit and enable them again when the total selection count goes below the maximum limit.

Here is the sample code,

```js
    function maxAllowedMultiselect(obj, maxAllowedCount) {
            var selectedOptions = jQuery('#'+obj.id+" option[value!=\'\']:selected");
            if (selectedOptions.length >= maxAllowedCount) {
                if (selectedOptions.length > maxAllowedCount) {
                    selectedOptions.each(function(i) {
                        if (i >= maxAllowedCount) {
                            jQuery(this).prop("selected",false);
                        }
                    });
                }
                jQuery('#'+obj.id+' option[value!=\'\']').not(':selected').prop("disabled",true);
            } else {
                jQuery('#'+obj.id+' option[value!=\'\']').prop("disabled",false);
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="userRequest_activity" name="activity[]" onchange="maxAllowedMultiselect(this, 2)" multiple>
  <option value="1">Bungee Jumping</option>
  <option value="2">Camping</option>
  <option value="3">Mountain Biking</option>
  <option value="4">Rappelling</option>
  <option value="5">Rock Climbing / Bouldering</option>
  <option value="6">Skiing</option>
  <option value="7">Wild Life (Safari)</option>
  <option value="8">Canoeing &amp; Kayaking</option>
  <option value="9">Rafting</option>
  <option value="10">Sailing</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/sp0o7bou/).

```
$("select option").click(function() {
    if ($("select option:selected").length > 3) {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        alert('You can select upto 3 options only');
    }
});
```

Comment: do i need to include jquery 1.9.2 file before the code?

Comment: @Anonymus, may i know which jQuery version you are using.

Comment: jquery version 1.11.0

Comment: yes you can go with that, no need to include jQuery 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if($("select option:selected").length > 3) { 
     alert('You can select upto 3 options only');
     $(this).removeAttr("selected");
  }

});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tmkzebnj/)

Comment: not working....the same problem it is having. Letting user select more than 3 options in this also

Comment: @Anonymus Can you check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me and it's simple, it show an alert and remove one selected option.

```js
<script>
    (function() {
        var x= document.getElementById("select");
        x.addEventListener("click",function() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
                if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
                    total = total + 1
                }
            }
            if (total > 3) {
                alert("please don't select more then 3 options")
                x.options[x.options.selectedIndex].selected=false
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom solution I built (in the Bootstrap ecosystem.) It will disable all non-selected options in the dropdown, and re-enable them when you de-select an option.

I modulated it to a function so you can easily pass your own identifier.
These loops can almost certainly be optimized, but I'll leave that to the reader.

```
    <select id="my_select" class="selectpicker form-control filter-select modal-filter-dropdown" data-width = "100%" multiple>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clear Selected Items</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</option>
    </select> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        selectWithLimit("#my_select", 3);

        function selectWithLimit(selector, selection_limit) {
          let num_selected = 0;

          // count number of selected options
          $(selector).change(function(event) {
            $(selector + ' option').each(function() {
              if($(this).is(':selected')) {
                num_selected++;
              }
            });

            // disable each option that is not selected if we're over the limit
            if (num_selected >= selection_limit) {
              $(selector + ' option').each(function() {
                if (!$(this).is(':selected')) {
                  if ($(this).val() != "Clear Selected Items") { 
                    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                  }
                }
              });

            // otherwise, enable all options
            } else {
              $(selector + ' option').each(function() {
                if (!$(this).is(':selected')) {
                  $(this).prop("disabled", false);
                }
              });
            }

            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            num_selected = 0;
          });
        }
      });
      
    </script>
```