# How can assign multiple selected values to the text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign the multiple selected values to the different text field. If i selected four option assign values to the four different text field.

Html code

```
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
<input type="text" id="opt1" />
<input type="text" id="opt2"/>
<input type="text" id="opt3" />
<input type="text" id="opt4" />
```

What i did sample jquery code

```
<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );  

    });
  })
  .trigger( "change" );
</script>
```

Please anybody help this. Thanks for your corporation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate `id` value based on the selected options index(you can get index value as the first argument of the callback function in [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) method) and update its value by selecting element using the generated `id`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
<input type="text" id="opt1" />
<input type="text" id="opt2" />
<input type="text" id="opt3" />
<input type="text" id="opt4" />

<script>
  $("select").change(function() {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function(i) {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
        $('#opt' + (i + 1)).val($(this).text());
      });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .trigger("change");
</script>
```

---

The much better approach would be using common `class` for inputs and you can get element by index using [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo-class selector in jQuery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
<input type="text" class="opt" />
<input type="text" class="opt" />
<input type="text" class="opt" />
<input type="text" class="opt" />

<script>
  $("select").change(function() {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function(i) {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
        $('.opt:eq(' + i + ')').val($(this).text());
      });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .trigger("change");
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE :** For limiting the number of selection always cache selected value in a global variable and restore when selected option count is greater than expected.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
<input type="text" class="opt" />
<input type="text" class="opt" />
<input type="text" class="opt" />
<input type="text" class="opt" />

<script>
  var sel;
  $("select").change(function() {
      var str = "",
        $selected = $("select option:selected");

      if ($selected.length > 4)
        $(this).val(sel);
      else
        sel = $(this).val();

      $selected.each(function(i) {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
        $('.opt:eq(' + i + ')').val($(this).text());
      });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .trigger("change");
</script>
```

Refer :  [Multiple Select limit number of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474614/multiple-select-limit-number-of-selection)

Comment: @Rijo : glad to help :)

Comment: @Rijo , If its proper solution.. you can mark it as Accepted answer.

Comment: one more help how can I limit maximum four selection

Comment: Thanks for your great help

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as,

using `trigger` in Jquery

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mh7Lvpug/1/)

```
 $("select option:selected").each(function(i) {
   if(i <= 4) {
      resVal += $(this).text() + " ";
      $('#opt' + (i + 1)).val($(this).text());
    }
  });

  $("div").text(resVal);
```

Comment: When I deselect how to reset all text field again

Answer (score 1):

Try like .Each time you select assign with different textbox . Increment the counter of each time click.It will match with the `ids` of textbox

```js
var count=1;
$( "select" ).change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "select" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).val() + " ";
    });
      $( "div" ).text( str );  

       $('#opt'+count).val(str);
  count ++;
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
<input type="text" id="opt1" />
<input type="text" id="opt2"/>
<input type="text" id="opt3" />
<input type="text" id="opt4" />
```

Comment: This answer is also fine :)

Comment: Its only allow the 4 select .check the answer @Rijo