# PHP multiple drop down list from database - how to restrict selections to 3

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, multipleselection

I created a drop down list using HTML/PHP for selecting multiple qualifications of a student. it works fine, but **I want to restrict the selection to 3 qualifications only**. Can any senior member guide me how to achieve it using PHP / MySql / HTML.

Here is the code

```
<select required id="JOBQUALIFICATION" name="JOBQUALIFICATION[]" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:300px">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
    <?php
        do {  
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_qmast['QMDESC']?>"><?php echo $row_qmast['QMDESC']?></option>
    <?php
        } while ($row_qmast = mysql_fetch_assoc($qmast));
    ?>
</select>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['JOBQUALIFICATION'])) {

$JOBQUALIFICATION=implode(',',$_POST['JOBQUALIFICATION']);
} else  {

$JOBQUALIFICATION="";
}
echo $JOBQUALIFICATION;
?>
```

Comment: Check this post out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474614/multiple-select-limit-number-of-selection

Comment: Add `LIMIT 3` to your query?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I think he's asking to stop allowing them to select more than 3 at once in a multiple select dropdown

Comment: @clearshot66 Right ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: @clearshot66 Thank you for the Link provided above

Answer (score 0):

disable the select after 3 are selected

```
<html>
<tite></title>
<head>
<!-- Import the Jquery files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head
<!-- Jquery Script --> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#JOBQUALIFICATION").change(function () {
              if($("#JOBQUALIFICATION option:selected").length > 3) {
                   $('#JOBQUALIFICATION').prop('disabled', false);
              }
          });

    });
        </script>
    <body>




<select required id="JOBQUALIFICATION" name="JOBQUALIFICATION[]" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:300px">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
    <?php
        do {  
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_qmast['QMDESC']?>"><?php echo $row_qmast['QMDESC']?></option>
    <?php
        } while ($row_qmast = mysql_fetch_assoc($qmast));
    ?>
</select>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['JOBQUALIFICATION'])) {

$JOBQUALIFICATION=implode(',',$_POST['JOBQUALIFICATION']);
} else  {

$JOBQUALIFICATION="";
}
echo $JOBQUALIFICATION;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt help; Where should I add the code? Does it require any tags like <script>?

Comment: You will need to add then between `<script></script>` tags and you will also need to have `jQuery` added in your project if it is not in there already. You will also need to have that script placed AFTER your PHP functions unless you surround it with a `document.load()` function, which is also `jQuery`.

Comment: @SagarPatra  I've modified my answer, see if that helps

Comment: Thank you all for prompt response. Found better options at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474614/multiple-select-limit-number-of-selection (Link provided by @clearshot66)