# How to set limit multiple select option

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id='optgroup' class="searchable" multiple='multiple'>
    <option value='11'>Maths</option>
              <option value='12'>Physics</option>
              <option value='13'>Chemistry</option>
              <option value='14'>Biology</option>
              <option value='15'>Computer Science</option>
              <option value='16'>Accounts</option>
              <option value='17'>Commerce</option>
              <option value='18'>Business Maths</option>
              <option value='19'>Economics</option>
              <option value='20'>History</option>
</select>
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/bMwNXw)**

This demo i used **MultipleSelect**[http://loudev.com/] Jquery plugin .

i want to **set limit** for selectable items. *For Example* select only any 4 items.

```
$('#optgroup').multiSelect({ selectableOptgroup: true ,
      selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control category-seletable ' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search'>",
  selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control category-selection' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search'>",

      });
```

i tried **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474614/multiple-select-limit-number-of-selection)** . But not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `afterSelect()` callback and `deselect()` to do this.

`this.$selectionUl` is the right area with all the options `display: none`(yes, all of them), those seleted options would set `display` to `list-item` and add a class `.ms-selected`. So we can calculate the selected numbers through `$(this.$selectionUl).find('.ms-selected').length`, if the numbers of selected options is greater than `4`, then `deselect` the one just selected.

```js
$("#optgroup").multiSelect({
  selectableOptgroup: true,
  selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control category-seletable ' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search'>",
  selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control category-selection' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search'>",
  afterSelect: function(data) {
    // data is an array within the values of the options just being selected
    if ($(this.$selectionUl).find('.ms-selected').length > 4) {
      // deselect the item with the value given in parameter(data)
      // the value can be either an array of string or a string
      $("#optgroup").multiSelect('deselect', data);
      console.log('You can only select 4 items!!')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/css/multi-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
<select id='optgroup' class="searchable" multiple='multiple'>
  <option value='11'>Maths</option>
  <option value='12'>Physics</option>
  <option value='13'>Chemistry</option>
  <option value='14'>Biology</option>
  <option value='15'>Computer Science</option>
  <option value='16'>Accounts</option>
  <option value='17'>Commerce</option>
  <option value='18'>Business Maths</option>
  <option value='19'>Economics</option>
  <option value='20'>History</option>
</select>
```