# How to limit a multi-select input field to a certain number selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-select field I want to limit a user to how many they can select.  There are 15 options to choose from in the list but I only want users to select a maximum of 5.  Here is my javascript so far.

I have checked the console in the developer tools and its just ignoring my code.  What am I missing?

I've tried several iterations of the codes but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ctl01_TemplateBody_WebPartManager1_gwpciMyAccount_ciMyAccount_AreasofExpertise_Name_Demo.GEO_SPEC').on('change', function(evt) {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if (selected.length > 5) {
      console.log("Warning: You can only select up to 5 options.");

      alert("You can only select up to 5 options.");

      $(this).val(Array.from(selected).slice(0, 5).map(option => option.value));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Select limit number of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474614/multiple-select-limit-number-of-selection)

Comment: Are you sure the selector is correct?

Comment: If you have an ID selector, you generally don't need a class selector as well, since the ID should uniquely identify the element.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.