# Number of selection in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possibile to limit number of selection in collection_select?

This is my form:

```
<%= f.collection_select :player_ids, players, :id, :lastname, {}, { multiple: true } %>
```

I want limit to only 2 selects.

Comment: It is possible using jQuery. [See here][1] for more details.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2046277/3243794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add select2 js in your project from this link : https://select2.github.io/
and then do this

```
$("#player").select2({
maximumSelectionSize: 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [chosen-select](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) with following syntax:

> $("#player_ids").chosen({max_selected_options: 2});