# Unable to deselect 'select multiple' options with selection counter and optgroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, optgroup

I'm using the code from the accepted answer here

[How do you limit options selected in a html select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046205/how-do-you-limit-options-selected-in-a-html-select-box)

to count the selected options in a 'select multiple' menu:

```
var last_valid_selection = null;    
$("#select_options").change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 10) {
        $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
    } else {
          last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
          $("#select_options_text").text("Please select at least one, and up to ten options. You have currently selected "+$(this).val().length); 
    }     
});
```

The menu is divided into six optgroups. When I hit 10 selections I can no longer make selections, as expected. But **I can also no longer use CTRL+click on selected options to deselect them**.

If I remove all optgroups, the menu functions correctly. It also functions correctly with one and two optgroups. It only seems to be when a third optgroup is added that the problem described above appears.

I have tested in Chrome and Firefox and the problem occurs in both.

Comment: Can you add your HTML, and even better, reproduca that in a jsfiddl

Comment: Reproduce issue on jsFiddle, works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/z9r26r3j/1/

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle using the actual select menu options: https://jsfiddle.net/gzdrL5wu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

You have duplicate options, so when try to restore the last selection by calling `$(this).val(last_valid_selection)`, you could be selecting more than one value than you actually want (i.e. you end up selecting more than 10).

For example, you have more than one `Biochemistry`, so when `last_valid_selection` contains one instance of `Biochemistry`, *all* the duplicate `Biochemistry` options will be selected.

**Solution**

Use a different way of remembering the last valid selections.

Here I present a solution using data attribute and individually store whether or not an option has been previously selected.

```
function save_selected(select){
    $(select).find("option").each(function(){
        var t = $(this);
        t.data("last-selected", t.is(":selected"));
    });
};

function load_selected(select){
    $(select).find("option").each(function(){
        var t = $(this);
        t.attr("selected", t.data("last-selected"));
    });
};

$("#select_options").change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 10) {
        load_selected(this);
    } else {
        save_selected(this);
    }
});
```

Using this method, each individual option element has its own "last selected" state stored in its own data attribute. There would be no duplicate conflicts.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/gzdrL5wu/12/