# limit Several Select Multiple

Tags: javascript, php, select

Amm Guys Please Help me. i have 3 select multiple. and i want to limit the selected options in every select multiple with different limit. for example on the first select, i want to limit it to 2 selected options only. On the second select, i want to limit it to 4 selected options only. on the third select, i want to limit it to 3 selected options only. im sorry. im new this. please help me. thank you

```
// total option that can be selected for this should be 2
<select multiple class='qwerty' size = "3" style = "width:10%;">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

 // total option that can be selected for this should be 4
<select multiple class='qwerty' size = "3" style = "width:10%;">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

// total option that can be selected for this should be 3
<select multiple class='qwerty' size = "3" style = "width:10%;">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>


                <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script language = "JavaScript">
                        var last_valid_selection = null;
                        $('.qwerty').change(function(event) {
                            if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
                              alert('You can only choose 2!');
                              $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
                            } else {
                              last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
                            }
                         });
                    </script>
             </script>
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046205/how-do-you-limit-options-selected-in-a-html-select-box.

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f19xuqp6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve `data-` attribute associated with the element. I assume the `size` attribute you wrote serves this purpose.

```
<select multiple class='qwerty' data-size="3" style="width:10%;">
```

You need isolated `last_valid_selection` for each of the `select` element. This can be achieved by creating a closure which captures an outer variable.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.qwerty').change((function () {
        var last_valid_selection = null; // closure variable private to each of the select element
        return function(event) {
            var limit = parseInt($(this).data('size')); // data API to get the attribute data-size
            if ($(this).val().length > limit) {
                alert('You can only choose ' + limit + '!');
                $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
            } else {
                last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
            }
         };
    })());
</script>
```

Refer to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34xroujm/1/) for the example.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! thank you so much!!! Thank you for your fast response! :) Been trying to figure out this for weeks. :)